# Mockito calls Object's equals() method

Tags: java, testing, mockito

I'm new in Mockito. 
I have

```
Map<String, Object> expectedFilter = new HashMap<String, Object>()
expectedFilter.put("ids", new Integer[]{22});
expectedFilter.put("codes", new Integer[]{1});
```

and write stubbing with using this map as argument. Why does mockito call Object's equals while the real type of value in the map is Integer?

Thanks!

Comment: "write stubbing with using this map as argument" <-- can you show the relevant code?

Comment: when(mock.call("some string", expectedFilter, 1, 500, false)).thenReturn(new Object[]{1, 2});

Comment: Uhm, more code, please, this is not enough (put it in your question)

Comment: In particular, why do you call this argument `expectedFilter`? If that is what you expect your mock to be called with, this should not be in a `when()`, but in a `verify()`

Comment: Ahlkanvorez has already answered. Thanks to all for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're putting Integer[] into the map, not Integers. Integer[] does not override Objects equals, so it will be called. To get around this you could write a wrapper class that calls equals on the contents of the array like this:

```
public class ArrayWrapper<E> {
  private E[] data;

  public ArrayWrapper(E[] data) {
    this.data = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length);
  }

  @Override public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (this == other) return true;
    if (!(other instanceof ArrayWrapper)) return false;
    ArrayWrapper o = (ArrayWrapper)other;
    if (this.data.size != o.data.size) return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.data.size; i++)
      if (!this.data[i].equals(o.data[i]) return false;
    return true;
  }
}
```

and add instances of this class to the map instead of Integer[]'s, so this classes equals will be called.

Comment: You are right, thanks!!!! In my app I can to change array to List, and it solved my problem :)